# JAVA 8 Extract predicates as fields or methods?

Tags: java-8, java-stream, predicates

What is the cleaner way of extracting predicates which will have multiple uses. Methods or Class fields?

The two examples:

1.Class Field

```
void someMethod() {
    IntStream.range(1, 100)
        .filter(isOverFifty)
        .forEach(System.out::println);
}

private IntPredicate isOverFifty = number -> number > 50;
```

2.Method

```
void someMethod() {
    IntStream.range(1, 100)
        .filter(isOverFifty())
        .forEach(System.out::println);
} 

private IntPredicate isOverFifty() {
    return number -> number > 50;
}
```

For me, the field way looks a little bit nicer, but is this the right way? I have my doubts.

Comment: Maybe make them a constant? `public static final IntPredicate IS_OVER_FIFTY = ...` Just use whatever you want, I'd also like the method version, but the method should be static.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Generally* you cache things that are expensive to create and these stateless lambdas are *not*. A stateless lambda will have a single instance created for the entire pipeline (under the current implementation). The first invocation is the most expensive one - the underlying `Predicate` implementation class will be created and linked; but this happens only once for both stateless and stateful lambdas.

A stateful lambda will use a different instance for each element and *it might* make sense to cache those, but your example is stateless, so I would not.

If you still want that (for reading purposes I assume), I would do it in a class `Predicates` let's assume. It would be re-usable across different classes as well, something like this:

```
 public final class Predicates {
     private Predicates(){
     }

     public static IntPredicate isOverFifty() {
          return number -> number > 50;
     }
 }
```

You should also notice that the usage of `Predicates.isOverFifty` inside a Stream and `x -> x > 50` while semantically the same, will have different memory usages.

In the first case, only a single instance (and class) will be created and served to all clients; while the second (`x -> x > 50`) will create not only a different instance, but also a different class for each of it's clients (think the same expression used in different places inside your application). This happens because the linkage happens per `CallSite` - and in the second case the `CallSite` is always different.

But that is something you should not rely on (and probably even consider) - these Objects and classes are fast to build and fast to remove by the GC - whatever fits your needs - use that.

Comment: up! detailed explaination. One mentioned maybe use method reference expression is more effectively and expressive, since it will make class smaller, e.g:`static boolean isOverFifty(int x)`, :)

Answer (score 0):

To answer, it's better If you expand those lambda expressions for old fashioned Java. You can see now, these are two ways we used in our codes. So, the answer is, it all depends how you write a particular code segment.

```
private IntPredicate isOverFifty = new IntPredicate<Integer>(){

 public void test(number){
  return number > 50;
 }

};


private IntPredicate isOverFifty() {
    return new IntPredicate<Integer>(){

          public void test(number){
             return number > 50;
          }

   };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1) For field case you will have always allocated predicate for each new your object. Not a big deal if you have a few instances, likes, service. But if this is a value object which can be N, this is not good solution. Also keep in mind that `someMethod()` may not be called at all. One of possible solution is to make predicate as `static` field.

2) For method case you will create the predicate once every time for `someMethod()` call. After GC will discard it.